# Uploading image to parse ios 9

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm creating an app that allows the user to upload text and an image either taken from library or from the camera and uploads to parse. I get the text to upload no problem but it only will upload the image to parse 1 in 20 tries. Any thoughts? I've posted my code.

```
@IBAction func saveData(sender: AnyObject) {

    var imageText = messageText.text
    var uploadDate = NSDate()
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
    formatter.stringFromDate(uploadDate)

    if messageText.text == nil {
        print("Image not uploaded")
    }else {
        var posts = PFObject(className: "Memento")
        posts["imageText"] = imageText
        posts["uploadTime"] = uploadDate
        posts["uploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
        posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imagePreview.image!)
                var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.png", data: imageData!)
                posts["imageFile"] = parseImageFile
                posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {
                        print("data uploaded")
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("saveHome", sender: self)

                    }else {
                        print(error)
                    }
                })
            } else {
                print(error)
            }

        })


    }


}
```

Comment: What error if any are you getting?  Why do you save the `posts` object twice?  Why not set the image and save it once?

Comment: I didn't necisarrily get in error. It just would only upload about 1 in 20 images to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to save the image file to Parse as well as adding it to your `posts` object.

```
@IBAction func saveData(sender: AnyObject) {

var imageText = messageText.text
var uploadDate = NSDate()
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle
formatter.stringFromDate(uploadDate)

if messageText.text == nil {
    print("Image not uploaded")
} else {

    // Save the image
    //var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imagePreview.image!)
    //var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.png", data: imageData!)
    var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.jpg", data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imagePreview.image!, 0.6)!)!
    parseImageFile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            println("picture saved")
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Picture Save Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    // Then save your posts object
    var posts = PFObject(className: "Memento")
    posts["imageText"] = imageText
    posts["uploadTime"] = uploadDate
    posts["uploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
    posts["imageFile"] = parseImageFile
    posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("data uploaded")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("saveHome", sender: self)
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Picture Save Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your changes Russell. However, now I get an exception that says "Failed to create PFFile with data: data is larger than 10MB."

Comment: As the error says, the picture that is being uploaded is too large. You will probably want to compress the photos before uploading them. I left it out originally because you didn't have it before. Check out the updated answer

Comment: I also converted it to JPEG format which you will want for normal photos. The 0.6 is the compression factor